# Term to define a specific tactic used when engaged in an argument

Tags: single-word-requests, expressions, verbs, phrase-requests, pejorative-language

As a tactic to "win" an argument, when one party has accepted responsibility for a specific action, the insatiable second party repeatedly finds/adds/remembers another infraction for the first party to acknowledge and accept responsibility for?

Comment: Nit-picking?  So-and-so "prolongs the argument"?  "Never satisfied"?

Comment: Nagging is another possibility. Could you give a sample from a typical conversation? The extra context might help.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds a lot like "moving the goalposts" or "raising the bar".

> [moving the goalposts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moving_the_goalposts) - Moving the goalposts (or shifting the goalposts) is a metaphor, derived from association football or other games, that means to change the criterion (goal) of a process or competition while still in progress, in such a way that the new goal offers one side an intentional advantage or disadvantage.

Answer (score 0):

I have heard ***perseveration*** used for this situation when then other person won't "drop it."

> [**perseveration** -](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/perseveration)
>
> continuation of something (as repetition of a word) usually to an exceptional degree or beyond a desired point

Also, [here](http://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/perseverate):

> When you persist with clear intentions, you persevere, but when those intentions are lost and only the persistence remains, you perseverate.

Answer (score 0):

There's a common saying that "if you give him an inch, he'll take a yard" (or variations with other units), meaning that a person responds to any concession by demanding further concessions.

To *press your advantage* means to intensify your efforts when you are winning.

The behaviour described by the OP sounds like a specific form of *bullying,* or *hectoring* or *cowing* etc.: one party is trying to act cooperatively while the other is using an approach based on dominance versus weakness.

Answer (score -1):

This sounds like [**filibustering**](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/filibuster) - An action such as a prolonged speech that obstructs progress while not technically contravening the required procedures.
Sort of just making up things to talk about in the hopes that the other party will give up and go away.

Comment: No, a filibuster is arguing at length to prevent resolution of the issue at hand.  Here, the "insatiable" party wants resolution, just on terms that he continually seeks to improve for himself.

Comment: Oh I like that Deadrat. What would a word be for someone who continually changes understood requirements? Person would also have the expectation that the newly necessary requirements  should have been intuitively known and now the lack of  intuition is up for discussion as well as the unmet requirements...if that makes any sense lol.

Comment: So the word we are looking for describes someone who genuinely wants to resolution but is fickle, or are we looking for the action of changing objectives? it sounds like the OP needs to be updated.

Comment: It is more like a shark becoming more aggressive when it smells blood. The moment the point is conceded the opponent uses the moment of perceived weakness to force more concessions.